# Gensim: how to extract Topics from a trained Doc2Vec model in Gensim?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I already have a trained doc2vec model.

```
model = Doc2Vec(size = 100, window = 10, min_count = 1, workers=4, hashfxn=hash32)
model.build_vocab(doc)
model.train(doc)
model.save(r'C:\Data\Model\hs8000_2016Q2.doc2vec')
```

model only has n_similarity or most_similar as function to check similarity between sentences. However, I want to know top 50 Topics in the model. how do I extract Topics from the model?

Thank you!